# XNA convert XNB effect to .FX

Tags: c#, xna, effect, xna-3.0

I need a way (if possible) to convert a compiled XNA 3.0 .XNB Effect file to a readable .fx file (to add it to a XNA 4.0 project again, since I dont have the original shader anymore).

Comment: Can't you use the compiled effect? With textures, you load them by name at run time, and this loads the compiled version.

Comment: @John The XNB format changed between versions, so the XNB file won't load. At a huge stretch you might be able to extract the effect binary itself - although the FX compiler also changed between XNA 3 and 4, so I'm entirely sure it would work, even if you did manage to repackage it.